# List untracked files only by specific file type

Tags: git

I have a lot of untracked files in Git repo. How to list untracked files only by a specific file type, say `*.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
git ls-files -o "*.py"
```

See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt--o).

*Upd*. Quotes in `"*.py"` are required to prevent the shell to interpret `*`. With the quotes it is Git that interprets the file mask.